# Python - fill NaN by range of date

Tags: python

I have a dataframe, when:

- one of column is a Date column.
- another column it's X column, that column have missing values.

I want to fill column X by a specific range of dates.

so far I got to this code:

```
df[df['Date'] < datetime.date(2017,1,1)]['X'].fillna(1,inplace=True)
```

But it dose not work, I am not getting an error, but the data isn't fill.
and another point it look messy, maybe there is a better way.

Thank for the help.

Comment: What is "does not work" ? Can you show a sample of the DF ?

Comment: try `df.loc[df['Date'] < datetime.date(2017,1,1), 'X'].fillna(1,inplace=True)`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create your data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2016-01-01', '2018-01-01']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Next, you can conditionally set the column value:

```py
df.loc[df['Date'] < '2017-01-01','X'] = 1
```

The result would be like this:

```
    Date        X
0   2016-01-01  1.0
1   2018-01-01  NaN
```